# Creating box plots of the gap between two groups by deciles

Tags: stata, boxplot

I work with Stata and I have math grades for two different groups: `A` and `B`.

I want to see the gap that exists between both groups in each decile. In addition I want to do a box plot of this gap for each decile (I want to have `10` box plots, one for each decile which shows the gap between group grades).

What I first did was to compute the deciles using `xtile` for both groups:

```
xtile decileA= mat if group==1, nq(10)

xtile decileB= mat if group==0, nq(10)
```

However, groups `A` and `B` do not have the same number of observations nor the same distribution. I thought of computing quantiles for each decile and group and subtracting them to get the difference in each decile at each quartile to create the boxplot. But I do not know how to proceed afterwards to create the graph, and given that I have a different number of observations in each group decile I do not know if it is correct to proceed this way.

If I try to use the `pctile` command and compute the difference at each decile, I lose all the variance in the data inside each decile. I only get median differences and not all the quantiles I want.

Example:

```
pctile decileA= mat if group==1, nq(10)

pctile decileB= mat if group==0, nq(10)

gen qdiff= decileA- decileB if _n<10

gen qtau=_n/10 if _n<10 

graph box qdiff, over(tau)
```

I want to know if there is a way to do the graph I am intending to?

Cross-posted on [Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1485443-views-creating-box-plots-of-the-gap-between-two-groups-by-deciles).

Comment: It seems to me that this is more of a statistical question than one of programming strict sense. Accordingly I answered on Statalist. Thus there are now answers on two sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is certainly a way to accomplish what you want with a bit of effort, but if the goal is to make a comparison between the two groups at each decile with some notion of variability, you can easily get that from a simultaneous quantile regression and the SEs that it produces:

```
sysuse auto, clear

sqreg price i.foreign, quantile(.1 .2 .3 .4 .5 .6 .7 .8 .9)

margins, dydx(foreign) ///
predict(outcome(q10))  ///
predict(outcome(q20))  ///
predict(outcome(q30))  ///
predict(outcome(q40))  ///
predict(outcome(q50))  ///
predict(outcome(q60))  ///
predict(outcome(q70))  ///
predict(outcome(q80))  ///
predict(outcome(q90))  ///
post

marginsplot, yline(0) xlab(, grid) ylab(#10, grid angle(90))
```

This yields a graph showing that foreign origin is associated with a bigger price at higher deciles, with the exception of the top decile, though none of the differences are probably significant here given how much the CIs overlap:

[image]

You can even conduct formal hypothesis tests that the effects are equal like this:

```
. test _b[1.foreign:9._predict] =  _b[1.foreign:8._predict]

 ( 1)  - [1.foreign]8._predict + [1.foreign]9._predict = 0

           chi2(  1) =    3.72
         Prob > chi2 =    0.0537
```

With 74 cars, we cannot reject that the effect on the 80th and 90th percentile are the same even though the point estimates have the opposite signs but similar magnitude.